# Change timeout for Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker at runtime?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, resilience4j, spring-cloud-circuitbreaker

I'm using Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker 2.0.0 (resilience4j implementation) for circuit breaking and timeouts in my application. I've created the following configuration:

```java
@Bean
public Customizer<Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
    return factory -> 
        factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom().timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).build())
                .circuitBreakerConfig(..)
                .build());
}
```

Now I want to write an integration test to verify that my behavior is correct when a timeout occurs. For this to work, I'd like to temporarily change the timeout duration specified in the configuration above to something like 1 millisecond instead of 10 seconds.

So my question is: How can I change the value of the timeout of the `TimeLimiterConfig`(temporarily) when I'm writing a Spring Boot integration test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@Value` [Spring annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation) that retrieves the value at a configuration file from your resource folder `src/main/resources/common.properties`.

```
@Bean
public Customizer<Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer(
    @Value("${duration.milli:600}") int durationMilli) {
    return factory -> 
        factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom().timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMilli(durationMilli)).build())
                .circuitBreakerConfig(..)
                .build());
}
```

Then you set the value at `src/main/resources/common.properties`

```
duration.milli=600
```

When you are doing your test you can configure another resource file at the `test` folder `src/test/resources/common.properties` with a different value.

```
duration.milli=1
```